# How do you update claims value for a *different* user in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

You can do it to refresh current logged in user by `signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync`. But how do you do the same for a *different* user?

To clarify, the "refresh" action should not log the *different* user out.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45347956/how-to-refresh-claim-of-a-different-user-than-the-one-logged-in-during-the-curre

Comment: I should say i wish not to log the "different" user out, only update its claim.

Comment: Can we see your startup.cs?

Comment: Is it relevant? A default template have the same scenario.

Comment: i try to publish a default startup.cs here, but it wouldn't let me as it exceeds max chars.